# Change request.url in Scrapy to crawl a json file then return to the original request

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am scraping data from an url (product name, price, etc.) but there is a json file in the backend which I also want to scrape as it has relevant information. In a nutshell I want to change my request url to the json one and and then return to the original url so the crawling can continue.

1. Product url:https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0906822002.html
2. Related json url (this can be found in the Networks tab, and I store this in a variable named availability_url):
   https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/0906822.json

It would be very important to have the availability data in a variable before the actual yield as I have to return to the original url before checking the colors at the end of the code:

```
import scrapy
import re

class HMSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hm'
    
    start_urls= ['https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/learazas/noi/dresses.html']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}

    def parse(self, response):
        
        items = response.css('h3.item-heading  a::attr(href)').getall()
        for item in items:
            link = 'https://www2.hm.com' + item
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response, request):
        page_source_data = response.xpath('//div[@class= "tealiumProductviewtag productview parbase"]//text()')[0].get()
        data = response.css('div.product.parbase script::text').get()
        base_product_code = re.findall("ancestorProductCode = '(.*)';",data)[0]
        detailed_product_code = re.findall("articleCode':'(.*)', 'baseProductCode",data)[0]
        current_price = int(re.findall(r'\d+',re.findall('product_list_price :  \["(.*?)\],', page_source_data)[0])[0])
        original_price = int(re.findall(r'\d+',re.findall('product_original_price : \[(.*?)\],', page_source_data)[0])[0])
        availability_url = 'https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/' + base_product_code +".json"
        info_url = "https://tags.tiqcdn.com/dle/hm/hdl/" + detailed_product_code +".json"

        if current_price != original_price:
            yield{
            'product_name': re.findall('(?<=  ).*$',response.css('section.name-price h1.primary.product-item-headline::text').get())[0],
            'vendor': 'H&M',
            'current_price': int(current_price),
            'original_price': int(original_price),
            'discount_percent': 100-round((current_price / original_price)*100),
            'colors': response.css('li.list-item a::attr(title)').getall(),
            'link': response.request.url,
            #rating
            #reviews
            }
            color_count = len(response.css('div.mini-slider li.list-item a::attr(href)').getall()) 
            if color_count > 1:
                additonal_colors = response.css('div.mini-slider li.list-item a::attr(href)').getall()
                color_index = 1
                for color in additonal_colors:
                    if color_index <= color_count:
                        link = 'https://www2.hm.com' + color
                        yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_item)
                        color_index += 1
```

So to sum up: I want to change the scraped url from
https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0906822002.html
to https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/0906822.json
then return back to
https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0906822002.html so my scraper can continue work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, if you do the json request after extracting all item data you don't have to return to the function. (The colour varaitions request will still be created since we're yielding requests and nothing returning)
Try if this works for you:

```
import json
import scrapy
import re

class HMSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hm'
    
    start_urls= ['https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/learazas/noi/dresses.html']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}

    def parse(self, response):
        
        items = response.css('h3.item-heading  a::attr(href)').getall()
        for item in items:
            link = 'https://www2.hm.com' + item
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response, request):
        page_source_data = response.xpath('//div[@class= "tealiumProductviewtag productview parbase"]//text()')[0].get()
        data = response.css('div.product.parbase script::text').get()
        base_product_code = re.findall("ancestorProductCode = '(.*)';",data)[0]
        detailed_product_code = re.findall("articleCode':'(.*)', 'baseProductCode",data)[0]
        current_price = int(re.findall(r'\d+',re.findall('product_list_price :  \["(.*?)\],', page_source_data)[0])[0])
        original_price = int(re.findall(r'\d+',re.findall('product_original_price : \[(.*?)\],', page_source_data)[0])[0])
        availability_url = 'https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/' + base_product_code +".json"
        info_url = "https://tags.tiqcdn.com/dle/hm/hdl/" + detailed_product_code +".json"

        if current_price != original_price:
            item = {
                'product_name': re.findall('(?<=  ).*$',response.css('section.name-price h1.primary.product-item-headline::text').get())[0],
                'vendor': 'H&M',
                'current_price': int(current_price),
                'original_price': int(original_price),
                'discount_percent': 100-round((current_price / original_price)*100),
                'colors': response.css('li.list-item a::attr(title)').getall(),
                'link': response.request.url,
                #rating
                #reviews
            }

            if availability_url:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url=availability_url,
                    callback=self.parse_availability,
                    meta={
                        'item': item
                    }
                )

            color_count = len(response.css('div.mini-slider li.list-item a::attr(href)').getall()) 
            if color_count > 1:
                additonal_colors = response.css('div.mini-slider li.list-item a::attr(href)').getall()
                color_index = 1
                for color in additonal_colors:
                    if color_index <= color_count:
                        link = 'https://www2.hm.com' + color
                        yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_item)
                        color_index += 1
        
    def parse_availability(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        json_data = json.loads(response.body)
        #do something with json data here and add it to item
        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea now, but the extra color part in the code does not run, it seems like it finish executing after running the parse_availability function and not returning back to the line with color_count. can you help with that please?

Comment: Hmm, it should run, try adding something like print("TEST") after the if availability_url: statement and see if that gets printed in the console, then you know if that part of the code is executed

Comment: I just reorganized my code, and it works like a charm. thank you very much!